# Who can I fix the MultiException regarding jersey hk2 SystemInjecteeImpl

Tags: rest, jersey, cdi, hk2

I have a J2EE application with Tomcat 8.5. Now I try to use CDI in a rest service based on jersey 2.26-b03. But when I try to invoke the method `deviceController.getDevices().get("2").getCurrentvalue()`in the rest service `allDevices()` in class     SimpleRestService     I get the MultiException:

```
WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=DeviceController,parent=SimpleRestfulService,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1466685742)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:74)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:214)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:237)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
at org.glassfish.jersey.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:83)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2064)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:711)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:653)
at org.glassfish.jersey.hk2.HK2InjectionManager.getInstance(HK2InjectionManager.java:269)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:136)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:75)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:280)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1084)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:418)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.
run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the 
dependencies of path.to.restservice.SimpleRestfulService errors were 
found
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies
(ClazzCreator .java:249)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
at org.glassfish.jersey.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate(RequestContext.java:83)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2064)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:711)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:653)
at org.glassfish.jersey.hk2.HK2InjectionManager.getInstance(HK2InjectionManager.java:269)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:136)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:75)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:280)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1084)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:418)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on 
path.to.restservice.SimpleRestfulService
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:389)
at 
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
at 
org.glassfish.jersey.hk2.RequestContext.findOrCreate 
(RequestContext.java:83)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2064)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.
internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:711)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService
(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:653)
at org.glassfish.jersey.hk2.HK2InjectionManager.getInstance 
      (HK2InjectionManager.java:269)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:136)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:75)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:280)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1084)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:418)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run 
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run
(TaskThread.jav a:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After that exception I additionally created the class `JerseyResourceConfiguration` and bind the bean (DeviceController) I want to inject to the rest service (`SimpleRestService`). But it didn't solve the problem. Next step I tried to inject it via the SimpleRestService-Constructor.

That did not help either. I also experiment with the dependencies of hk2 (see pom.xml - at the moment the hk2-dependencies comment out).

The simple rest service

```
@Path("simple")
@RequestScoped
public class SimpleRestfulService {

    @Inject
    private DeviceController deviceController;


    //private final DeviceController deviceController;

    //@Inject
    //public SimpleRestResource(DeviceController deviceController){ 
    //      this.deviceController = deviceController;
    //}



    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("devices")
    public Response allDevices() 
    {
      System.out.println("DeviceController: " + this.
          deviceController.getDevices().get("2").getCurrentvalue());

          return Response
                  .status(200)
                  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                  .entity("{\"success\":\"Message received\"}")
                  .build();
    }
}
```

DeviceController (Bean to inject)

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class DeviceController implements Serializable {

      //methods like getDevices()

}
```

ApplicationCinfiguration class

```
@ApplicationPath("/api/v1")
public class RESTApplicationConfiguration extends Application {
}
```

The JerseyConfiguration class

```
public class JerseyResourceConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

     public JerseyResourceConfiguration() {
            packages("path.to.restservice");   //SimpleRestSrevice
            register(new AbstractBinder() {

                  @Override
                  protected void configure() {
                      bind(new 
                           DeviceController()).to(DeviceController.class);
                  }
              });
     }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I moved the @ApplicationPath from ApplicationConfiguration class

```
public class RESTApplicationConfiguration extends Application {
}
```

to JerseyConfiguration class

```
@ApplicationPath("/api/v1")
public class JerseyResourceConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

     public JerseyResourceConfiguration() {
            packages("path.to.restservice");   //SimpleRestSrevice
            register(new AbstractBinder() {

                  @Override
                  protected void configure() {
                      bind(new 
                           DeviceController()).to(DeviceController.class);
                  }
              });
     }
}
```

The simple rest service

```
@Path("simple")
@RequestScoped
public class SimpleRestfulService {

    @Inject
    private DeviceController deviceController;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("devices")
    public Response allDevices() 
    {
      System.out.println("DeviceController: " + this.
          deviceController.getDevices().size());

          return Response
                  .status(200)
                  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                  .entity("{\"success\":\"Message received\"}")
                  .build();
    }
}
```

But now in the SimpleRestfulService I get not the current state of the bean DeviceController. In the method allDevices() I try to print the size of getDevices() from DeviceController. But I always get zero. But In the bean itself it prints out e.g. 20.

Current pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
<!--
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26-b04</version>
</dependency>
-->

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.chartistjsf</groupId>
    <artifactId>ChartistJSF</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>      
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.26-b03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.26-b03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.26-b03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.26-b03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.26-b03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.7-dmr</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.SP1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I expect that the `DeviceController` bean can be injected successfully to the rest service `SimpleRestService` an invoke the device list. I also tried different solutions from other questions with the hk2-dependencies but the result is always the same.

Can anybody see whats wrong?

Comment: Your `JerseyResourceConfiguration` is not the configuration class being used. The one being used is `RESTApplicationConfiguration`. Delete the latter class and put the `@ApplicationPath` on the former. FYI, `ResourceConfig` extends `Application`.

Comment: You also need to stick to one Jersey version. You are using multiple versions in your dependencies, which might cause you some problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @paul-samsotha. I deleted RESTApplicationConfiguration and moved ApplicationPath to the JerseyResourceConfiguration. But now in the SimpleRestfulService I get not the current state of the bean DeviceController. In the method allDevices() I try to print the size of getDevices() from DeviceController. But I always get zero. But in the bean itself it prints out e.g. 20. I updated my code in the question above under UPDATE 1.

Comment: I do not know _why_ you are supposed to get what you are expecting as the code you posted is not implemented.